# changing default shell to /bin/bash of at job scheduler like in CRON

Tags: shell, ubuntu, at

I recently switched from `2>&1 >>` to  `&>>`

Is there a way to have **at** use /bin/bash as the shell? By default it uses /bin/sh and the man page gives no indication how anything else can be used.  Even in a `crontab` one can use `SHELL=/bin/bash`

The main problem this has been causing me is that in:

```
echo "do-smth.sh &>> logfile" | at now + 8 hours
```

instead of appending both stdout and stderr to my logfile, they have been getting lost altogether, not even getting emailed.

This workaround didn't work, citing unexpected redirection:

```
echo "bash <<< \"do-smth.sh &>> logfile\"" | at now + 8 hours
```

I use Linux, Ubuntu 11.10 flavor, which shouldn't matter.

Comment: It seems for now it can't be changed because the **at daemon** hardwires `/bin/sh` somewhere.  My workarounds to call `bash` complicate and make for very confusing double/triple quote escaping.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the way your command is written, `sh` is trying to handle the herestring redirection, and (being linked to `dash`, not `bash`, in Ubuntu) it doesn't have the `<<<` operator. You probably want this:

```
echo 'bash -c "do-smth.sh &>>logfile"' | at now + 8 hours
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record here's what I'm getting by with, in one use case.  Notice how *badly* it's obfuscated due to unavoidable single- or double-quote escaping:

```
      pidof -x pngcrush || at now <<< 'time nice bash -c '\''
(for f in $(find orderlog/ -mtime -1 -name \*.png); 
do convert -trim +repage -colors 64 -depth 6 -verbose $f $f.tmp; 
ls -lFa $f*; 
touch -r $f $f.tmp && mv -f $f.tmp $f; 
done;  
time find orderlog/ -mtime -3 -name \*.png -execdir  pngcrush -bit_depth 8 -d ~/tmp -oldtimestamp {} + ; 
mv -fv ~/tmp/*.png orderlog/; 
timeout 1h time find orderlog/ -mtime -2  \( -name \*.png -o -name \*.gif \) -execdir  optipng -keep -preserve -o6 -v  {} + ; 
rm -vf orderlog/*.png.{bak,tmp} ) &> orderlog/imgshrink.log'\'' '
```

Newlines added only here for readability.

Since it's inside a script it's grown to where I should turn it into a here-document for **at** to read, except I am afraid of breaking the (non)parse for **bash**.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it with `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script that cron runs?  If you create a directory with the scripts you are going to be using you can put that under source control and make it easier to recover if you lose access to this hard drive.  You can also install those scripts with puppet or chef or ansible and just add the single line entries in the crontab to run those scripts.